How to dynamically update drag ghost image text during drag operation in React?
I'm trying to update the text of a custom drag ghost image while dragging over specific elements. However, the ghost image text doesn't update even though the state changes.
Here's my code:
export const DndPage = () => {
  const handleOnDrag = useCallback((event) => {
    const ghost = document.getElementById('ghost');
    event.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'copy';
    event.dataTransfer.setDragImage(ghost, 0, 0);
    event.dataTransfer.setData('text', 'text');
  }, []);

  const [text, setText] = useState('');
  const [dragText, setDragText] = useState('');

  const renderItemToDrag = useCallback(
    (text: string) => {
      return (
        <>
          <div
            id='drag-zone'
            draggable
            onDragStart={handleOnDrag}
            style={{
              border: '1px solid black',
              padding: '10px',
              width: '50%',
              marginBottom: '10px',
            }}
          >
            <span>{text}</span>
          </div>
          <div
            id='ghost'
            style={{
              position: 'absolute',
              top: '-1000px',
              width: '100px',
              height: '30px',
              display: 'flex',
              justifyContent: 'center',
              alignItems: 'center',
              textAlign: 'center',
            }}
          >
            Copy to {dragText}
          </div>
        </>
      );
    },
    [dragText]
  );

  return (
    <>
      {renderItemToDrag('this is a draggable')}

      <div
        id='drop-zone'
        onDrop={(e) => {
          const data = e.dataTransfer.getData('text');
          setText(data);
        }}
        onDragOver={(e) => {
          e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'none';
          if ((e.target as HTMLElement).className === 'infomation') {
            e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'copy';
            setDragText('infomation');
          }
          e.preventDefault();
        }}
        style={{
          display: 'flex',
          flexDirection: 'column',
          gap: '10px',
          width: '400px',
        }}
      >
        <h3 className='infomation'>Drop area</h3>
        <span
          style={{ border: '1px solid black', padding: '10px', width: '200px' }}
        >
          {text}
        </span>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};


Expected behavior:

When dragging over the element with class "information", the ghost image should update to show "Copy to information"
The ghost text should update in real-time as I drag over different elements

Current behavior:

The ghost image text remains static and doesn't update during the drag operation
State updates (setDragText) don't reflect in the ghost image

I've tried:

Using useState to update the ghost text
Using useRef to reference the ghost element
The state (dragText) does update correctly, but the ghost image doesn't reflect the changes

Is it possible to update a drag ghost image's content during a drag operation? If so, how can I achieve this?

It is not possible to change the drag image after it has been set in the dragstart callback function.

This method [setDragImage()] must be called in the dragstart event handler.

DataTransfer: setDragImage() method
And updating the source of the image will not generate a new one.

so do we have solutions for this?
